# Why does Chocolatey fail to install when provisioning a Windows 7 VM using Vagrant?

Tags: windows, vagrant, chocolatey

I am attempting to automate the creation of a Windows 7 development environment using [Packer (v.0.8.6)](https://www.packer.io/), [Vagrant (v.1.8.1)](https://www.vagrantup.com/) , [VirtualBox (v.5.0.10)](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), and [Chocolatey (v.0.9.9.11)](https://chocolatey.org/) on a Windows 8.1 host.

I have managed to create the base Windows 7 SP1 box using Packer and I am attempting to create the Virtual Machine with Vagrant using `vagrant up`. The first thing I want to do is to install Chocolatey so that I can easily provision other software.

However. I have been unsuccessful in doing so. I have tried various incantations in my Vagrantfile. Here are the contents.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "windows_7"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    vb.gui = true
  end

  # option 1
  # config.vm.provision "shell", "inline": "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"

  # option 2
  # config.vm.provision "shell", "path": "./scripts/install-chocolatey.cmd"

  # option 3
  # config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/install-chocolatey.ps1"
end
```

```
# ./scripts/install-chocolatey.cmd
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%systemdrive%\vagrant\scripts\install-chocolatey.ps1"
```

```
# ./scripts/install-chocolatey.ps1
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

The error that I received for any of these options is:

```
==> default: Everything is Ok
==> default:
==> default: Files: 76
==> default: Size:       4893948
==> default: Compressed: 1806765
==> default: out-lineoutput : The OS handle's position is not what FileStream expected. Do n
==> default: ot use a handle simultaneously in one FileStream and in Win32 code or another F
==> default: ileStream. This may cause data loss.
==> default:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [out-lineoutput], IOException
==> default:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comma
==> default:    nds.OutLineOutputCommand
==> default:
```

However, if I manually run either option 1, 2, or 3 from a Cmd or PowerShell window on the virtual machine, chocolatey installs fine.

I searched for this error online and it appears to be a [PowerShell 2 and 3 bug](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2008/07/30/workaround-the-os-handles-position-is-not-what-filestream-expected/). Indeed, if I manually install PowerShell 4 on the Virtual Machine and run `vagrant provision` to re-provision it these options work.

But if that is the case why can I install chocolatey manually but not via Vagrant? I would like to use chocolately to upgrade PowerShell as it would be much easier to do so in an automated way.

How can I instruct Vagrant to install Chocolatey on my virtual machine without first upgrading PowerShell to a newer version?

---

Workaround Attempt 1:

I tried downgrading VirtualBox from 5.0.10 to 4.3.28 to see if there were the issue (per a recommendation). However, I was unable to run 4.3.28 on my host machine as I received an error when trying to create a new virtual machine, even out of the box, no packer or vagrant. Reinstalling 5.0.10 resolved that particular issue.

---

Workaround Attempt 2:

I applied the Powershell 2 workaround script [defined here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2008/07/30/workaround-the-os-handles-position-is-not-what-filestream-expected/) to my install-chocolatey.ps1 script. The full contents then became:

```
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetField"
$objectRef = $host.GetType().GetField("externalHostRef", $bindingFlags).GetValue($host)

$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetProperty"
$consoleHost = $objectRef.GetType().GetProperty("Value", $bindingFlags).GetValue($objectRef, @())

[void] $consoleHost.GetType().GetProperty("IsStandardOutputRedirected", $bindingFlags).GetValue($consoleHost, @())
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetField"
$field = $consoleHost.GetType().GetField("standardOutputWriter", $bindingFlags)
$field.SetValue($consoleHost, [Console]::Out)
$field2 = $consoleHost.GetType().GetField("standardErrorWriter", $bindingFlags)
$field2.SetValue($consoleHost, [Console]::Out)

iex -Debug ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

This allowed Chocolatey to install. However, I am unable to issue `choco` statements from Vagrant provisioners or from cmd line or a PowerShell windows until I reboot the machine. Once rebooted these become available, however, this causes the provisioning to fail. It is my understanding that I should not need to reboot the machine to use Chocolatey. I should only need to restart the shell. Inspecting the PATH variable I see that Chocolatey has not been added to the PATH which would explain the issue.

Comment: It's possible that the Lee Holmes workaround should be promoted into the Vagrant powershell provisioner. I can install Chocolatey directly from the guest powershell console, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you see the PowerShell error message when there is a log to one stream (such as stdout) followed by a log to another stream (such as stderr), usually involving writing output to a file path.

There is an error occurring, but unfortunately PowerShell is swallowing it and reproducing other issues - you can add `$env:ChocolateyDebug` before your call to install Chocolatey and see if it helps point towards where the error is occurring.

If I had to guess it is likely related to Chocolatey attempting to install .NET Framework 4.0 and running into errors. In my vagrant repo, I tend to separate the steps of .Net 4 install to something separate from Chocolatey. That repo is at [vagrant-windows-puppet](https://github.com/ferventcoder/vagrant-windows-puppet).

Comment: I have added `$env:ChocolateyDebug = 'true'` to the install-chocolatey.ps1 file, before installation of Chocolatey and unfortunately I do not see any additional error information in the vagrant output. I also tried `$env:ChocolatelyEnvironmentDebug = 'true'`. I have also confirmed that I have .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 installed on the base image. Chocolatey would not try to install these since they already exist, right?

Comment: You can also redirect all output to stdout so that you don't get the error but you will see the actual error.

Comment: I tried wrapping the command in `Start-Transaction/Stop-Transaction`. I also tried redirecting output via 2>&1. Neither option shows me any more info and I receive the same error error message in the console via Vagrant.

Comment: I'll try to get you something you can try soon. Did you get a chance to validate it happens when using the above repo?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this behavior on the above repo.